# How to move Rails app + pgsql database from localhost to my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am assuming I have to use capistrano but still unsure. I want to move my rails app and the databases (since they already have lot of data now) to the server, how can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capistrano to build a deployment system.  I personally use git to promote my apps to production.  I use Engine Yard (www.engineyard.com) and Heroku (www.heroku.com) for hosting.  Deployment is super-simple with both.

As far as the database goes it depends on your server implementation.  Most likely you'll need to backup and restore the database into production.

Comment: Richard - I am using git so basically I can just pull the repo to my server and manually upload the database ? will this be enough ?

Comment: If you are comfortable restoring the database then yes.  Pull the repo, run rake db:migrate, and and other rake tasks you need.  Copy up the database file and set up Postgres to use it.  Make sure your database.yml file points to the right place and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

to move your database schema... `rake db:schema:dump`  will dump it to schema.rb and `rake db:schema:load` will load them.