# How to transfer Postgres localhost development database data to production database on server in Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have created the test, production and development databases on server manually but not able to figure out, how to transfer data from local myapp_development database to myapp_production database on the server ?

I searched and found this [How to move Rails app + pgsql database from localhost to my server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15081590/692622), capistrano is giving me lot of errors and I am sure there must be a standard Rails way or postgres way to do this as exporting data as dump and again importing it though I may have to do it if I can't find anything better.

Answer (score 4):

You can dump the database using `pg_dump` then scp the database dump up to the database and run it on the server using `psql databse_name < database.dump`

Answer (score 1):

I use yaml_db gem. It can dump your data into a file and then load it back into the database. It's written using activerecord so it works with most databases.

URL: https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

```
rake db:data:dump   ->   Dump contents of Rails database to db/data.yml
rake db:data:load   ->   Load contents of db/data.yml into the database
```

Prefix the commands with RAILS_ENV=development or RAILS_ENV=production to choose target and destination scheme.

Comment: Boris, it looks good but from the yaml_db page - "Users, permissions, schemas, triggers, and other advanced database features are not supported - by design." , well I do need the users data to be exported

Comment: You want to export PostgreSQL users? Aren't you use just one PostgreSQL user to access your schema?Also I would recommend to give the production user different password, so that no development script can accidently be run against production database.